# configurationManager does not exist in the namespace System.Configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2005

I have used the following namespace to connect my project to the sql server:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

and also used

```
string str=System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myconnection"];
SqlConnection oconnection = new SqlConnection(str);
oconnection.Open();
```

when I run the program ,an error has been occurred and show the message

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings' is
>   obsolete.This method is obsolete,it has been replaced by
>   'System.Configuration!
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings '

but I have no found ConfigurationManager in that namespace and for `oconnection.Open();` the message is

> InvalidOperationException

was unhandled.

What can I do?

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings has been replaced - you should use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` instead (as the message explains). You may need to add a reference to the System.Configuration assembly. 
As for the exception when you try to open the SqlConnection, I'd suggest to log the complete exception (message + stacktrace) - to get more information.

Answer (score 85):

Go to references, and add a reference to `System.Configuration`

Once you have done this, you should be able to reference `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

```
string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnection"];
SqlConnection oconnection = new SqlConnection(str);
oconnection.Open();
```

From MSDN:
The `ConfigurationManager` class enables you to access machine, application, and user configuration information. This class replaces the `ConfigurationSettings` class, which is deprecated.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

---

**Edit: Addiitonal Information**

In reference to the `InvalidOperationException`.  This is caused when the connection string does not specify a data source or server.  I am guessing that your connection string is empty.

In your web.config check the location of your connection string.  If it falls under the  element, then you will need to change your code to search `ConnectionStrings` and not `AppSettings`.

```
string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: brother thanks for your advise.but there is no ConfigurationManager.i have done according to your suggest.again thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've added a referenece to System.Configuration assembly?  Many project types will not come with this reference loaded and you will have to do it manually

Comment: thanks Jeffery Khan,i have got ConfigurationManager.but another problem has been seen.The problem is for oconnection.Open(); and the message is  InvalidOperationException was unhandled(Instance failure).please dear,again help me.Thanks again for your cordiality

Comment: This solution worked in my case aswell, thanks, Khan!

Answer (score 30):

If you have multiple projects in the solution you have to add the reference `System.Configuration` to each of them for `ConfigurationManager` to work in any of them.

Comment: Wow, that is very strange... but it is the right answer.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out until I found this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Why isn't this prominent in the documentation? Sigh... But thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 18):

Add a reference of :  System.Configuration.dll in your project, then ConfigurationManager will be availiable

Answer (score 1):

Install System.Configuration from nuget package.
Then add reference.